# Can I impersonate a user on a different Active Directory domain in .NET?

Tags: .net, active-directory, cross-domain, impersonation

I have two Active Directory domains, A and B.  Users in domain A need to run an application on their desktops to view and manipulate a resource located on a server in domain B.  Each user also has an account in domain B.  Is it possible to impersonate each user's domain B identity to perform operations on the domain B resource programatically?

Example Workflow:

1. User logs in to domain A.
2. User launches desktop application.
3. User specifies resource in domain B.
4. Application prompts user for domain B credentials.
5. Application impersonates user's domain B identity to access specified resource.
6. User manipulates domain B resource using application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to speak in terms of Win32 APIs, but I'm pretty sure you can p/invoke to these from .NET.  Check http://pinvoke.net.

You need to call the LogonUser API to create an access token that represents the user's domain B credentials.

Then you call ImpersonateLoggedOnUser, passing in that access token.  The calling thread will impersonate the domain B credentials until you impersonate a different set of credentials or call the RevertToSelf API.

I guess it goes without saying that, for the LogonUser call to succeed, the machine you're running on will need to trust domain B.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around.. I mean, doesn't Domain B have to trust Domain A?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  No trust relationship has to exist between domains A and B.  But depending on which domain the machine belongs to, there may be some other trust necessity that we haven't mentioned.

Comment: It is my understanding that LogonUser does not authenticate remote users.  I have tried to use this method with WindowsImpersonationContext unsuccessfully.

LogonUser: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx

If this is not the case, then I'm beginning to think my problems may lie elsewhere.  It may be a trust issue between the two domains.  I'll check into that.

Comment: Unsure what's meant by "remote users".  Certainly, LogonUser takes a domain parameter and can issue tokens based on successful authentication by the appropriate domain server.

Comment: My apologies, I think I misunderstood the MSDN article that I linked to.  It can't be used 'to log on to a remote computer'.

So since it can be used to authenticate against a different domain, I'm beginning to suspect that my problem lies elsewhere.  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 11):

If your computer (the one doing the impersonation) is a member of a domain which does not trust the domain of the user account you are trying to impersonate, then impersonation will fail. Anybody who says otherwise, I would love to see proof.

Comment: Exactly.  What you need to do is establish a trust between the two AD domains.  This is not hard to do, but it does "open up" security between the two significantly, and is not a "neutral" decision to make.  It has a lot of implications.  Now I don't know if you NEED to have a trust relationship to impersonate, but I'd be very surprised if you didn't.  But I know it works if you DO have a trust (it's something I had to code in the last two weeks).